# Can I use fscanf to get only digits from text that contain chars and ints?

Tags: c, scanf

I want to extract digits from a file that contains characters and digits.

For example:

```
+ 321 chris polanco 23
```

I want to skip the '+' and get only the 321.

Here's the code I have so far.

```
while(fscanf(update, "%d", &currentIn->userid) != EOF){
    currentIn->index = index;
    rootIn = sort(rootIn, currentIn);
    index = index + 1;
    currentIn = malloc(sizeof(Index));
}
```

I was thinking that since I had `%d` that it would get the first digits that it finds but I was wrong. I'm open to better ways of doing this if you guys have any.

Comment: Using `std::string` will lead to syntax errors in C programs.

Comment: my program's written in c. i think that's C++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of struggling with fscanf() (and running into format problems later), I recommend to use [**fgets()**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/fgets.html) + [**sscanf()**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/scanf.html) combination to process each line.

If you know the the integer you are interested in starts at 3rd position in each line of the file then you can do `line+2` in sscanf() to read it. Otherwise, you can modify the sscanf() format string according to the format of your input file.

```
char line[MAX_LINE_LEN + 1];

While ( fgets(line, sizeof line, update) )
{
  if(sscanf(line+2, "%d",  &currentIn->userid) != 1)
  {
   /* handle failure */
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to make char line more general. What if we don't know the length?

Comment: fgets() will read only the specified number of bytes, so no problem there. If it could read a whole line, it'll continue from where it left in the next iteration (btw, it may cause problem with the *location* of the integer you want to read). Otherwise, you can scan each `line` (before doing sscanf() on it) and ignore until you see a `\n` character so that you know you are in the next line.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (fscanf(update, "%*[^0-9]%d", &currentIn->userid) == 1)
{
    ...
}
```

This skips over non-digits (that's the `%*[^0-9]` part) followed by an integer.  The suppressed assignment isn't counted, so the `== 1` ensures that you got a number.

Unfortunately, it runs into a problem if the first character in the file is a digit — as pointed out by [Chris Dodd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16406/chris-dodd).  There are multiple possible solutions to that:

1. `ungetc('a', update);` will give a non-digit to read first.
2. `while ((fscanf(update, "%*[^0-9]"), fscanf(update, "%d", &currentIn->userid)) == 1)`
3. Or:

   ```
   while (fscanf(update, "%*[^0-9]%d", &currentIn->userid) == 1 ||
          fscanf(update, "%d", &currentIn->userid) == 1)
   {
       ...
   }
   ```

Depending on which you think is more likely, you could reverse the order of these two `fscanf()` policies.  With the `scanf()` family of functions, there's always a problem if the string of digits is so long that the number cannot be represented in an `int`; you get undefined behaviour.  I don't attempt to address that.

This will pick up multiple numbers per line, one per invocation.  If you want a single number per line, or otherwise want control over how each line is handled, then use `fgets()` or `readline()` to read the line, and then `sscanf()` to do the analysis.  One advantage of this is that if you so choose, you can use careful functions like `strtol()` to convert digits to numbers.

Comment: This will fail if the line begins with a number (if there are no non-digits to skip).  You need `while ((fscanf(update, "%*[^0-9]"), fscanf(update, "%d", &currentIn->userid)) == 1)` instead, which is kind of ugly.

Comment: Oh, yes, you're right.  When there's no junk before the first digit, it fails.  I guess an initial `ungetc('a', update);` is almost as ugly as the double `fscanf()`, though it also works and doesn't afflict every iteration of the loop.